getusereffectivepermissions via power automate
I have been trying to use the _api/web/getUserEffectivePermissions(@u)?@u='i:0#.f|membership|username@domain.com call using the HTTP SharePoint Connector. but no matter how I try the username I either get High and Low as 0.
If I try a variation of the call: _api/web/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='principalName=username@domain.com I get the following error:

"status": 404, "message": "The user does not exist or is not unique.\r\nclientRequestId: b2a9c995-f221-4818-99ac-2ce4ece48234\r\nserviceRequestId: 1ce75aa1-50a9-6000-8644-061becf7455b", "source": https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site-name]/_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='principalName=username@domain.com', "errors": [ "-2130575276", "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException" ]}

has anyone been able to do make this call work in Power Automate?

You cannot use # in a query! You must encode it (with encodeUriComponent for example).

# is %23
| is %7C

Request:
_api/web/getUserEffectivePermissions('i:0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Clogin@your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com')

Response:
{
    "d": {
        "GetUserEffectivePermissions": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.BasePermissions"
            },
            "High": "432",
            "Low": "1011030767"
        }
    }
}

Power Automate flow:
encodeUriComponent(concat('i:0#.f|membership|', variables('User')))



